# Reals Sequence Proof

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose that $z_n = x_n + iy_n$, with $x_n$ and $y_n$ real. Prove that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} z_n = x + iy$ with
$x$ and $y$ real if and only if ${\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}} {x_n} = x$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} y_n = y$.

Answer (score 1):

Use $\operatorname{Re}(z)\leq |z|$ and $\operatorname{Im}(z)\leq|z|$ for every $z\in\mathbb{C}$ for one implication, and triangular inequality for the reverse one

Answer (score 0):

One direction is easy; for the other, you can use the fact that both $\mathrm{Im}$ and $\mathrm{Re}$ are continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Both $=>$ and $<=$ are clear.
This is in fact the definition of convergence of limit of complex number.

Comment: It's not exactly the definition, albeit it is clearly equivalent ($\mathbb{C}$ is a metric space, convergence of a sequence is defined the "usual" way ($\exists z\in\mathbb{C},\ \forall\varepsilon>0 \exists N\in\mathbb{N}\ \forall n\geq N\ |z_n-z|\leq\varepsilon$)).

Answer (score 0):

This is a special case of the fact that $x_n\in\mathbb{R}^m$ converges to $x\in\mathbb{R}^m$ w.r.t. the Euclidean metric iff $x_{n,i}\in\mathbb{R}$ converges to $x_i\in\mathbb{R}$ for all $i\in\{1,2,\dots,m\}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:  $$|z_n-(x+iy)|=|(x_n-x)+i(y_n-y)|\le|x_n-x|+|i(y_n-y)|=|x_n-x|+|y_n-y|$$ and $$|z_n-(x+iy)|\ge\max\{|x_n-x|,|y_n-y|\}$$